# How Do You Catch Exceptions from All Child Processes of multiprocessing.Pool()?

Tags: python, error-handling, multiprocessing

How do I catch the errors from every child process when using `multiprocessing.Pool()` in Python? The code below is failing for three of ten child processes in `a_function`:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
    try:
        result = a_class.a_function(arg_1, arg_2, p)
        logging.info(f"Completed\n")
    except:
        logging.error("Failed\n")
        raise
```

*The returns are as follows:*

> `ERROR Failed`

> `ERROR index 1585 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1585`

> `ERROR index 1585 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1585`

> `Traceback...`

It looks to me like the `Except` only catches an error from at most one child process.

*I would expect to see the following return instead:*

> `ERROR Failed`

`sys.exit()` doesn't work for this purpose, since it stops the code entirely without allowing for next steps to execute (in this case, updating the user that the code has failed). Adding `try`/`except` blocks within `a_function`, adding `p.close()` to the `except` block, and adding `p.terminate()` to the `except` block didn't make a difference in the returns.

Is there a simple way to rewrite a `multiprocessing.Pool()` with a `try`/`except` block that can catch errors in **all** the child processes (and give the expected return above)?

Answer (score 0):

You really should have posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which shows how you are actually using the pool, `p`. If you want to catch all errors there are multiple ways. You can use method `apply_async` with the *error_callback* argument specified or you could use, for example, method `imap` and then iterate the returned *iterable* in a `while True` loop using the explicit `next` function enclosed within a try/except and exiting the loop when you get a `StopIteration` exception signifying there are no more results.

**Method 1**

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def worker(x):
    raise ValueError(x)

def error_callback(e):
    print('Got Exception:', e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    for x in range(8):
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(x,), error_callback=error_callback)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**Method 2**

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def worker(x):
    raise ValueError(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    result = pool.imap(worker, range(8)) # Or method imap_unordered
    while True:
        try:
            return_value = next(result)
            print(return_value)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('Got Exception:', e)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! My bad about leaving out the reproducible example, the `a_function` above calls multiple functions that each use `p`, so I wasn't able to type it all out, but I should have found a way to. I ended up solving this by skipping the `raise` when there's an error, and doing a `return e` instead. The return takes the code back to the parent function, where the `try`/`except` block catches the exception and updates the user, and the child processes do not proceed due to the `return`.